# css show button over image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a simple `reactjs` app where I need to put a `button` over image. 
My html looks like:

```
<div className={"panel-body"}>
    <img className={"img-responsive center-block"}
         src={album.photos.data[0].source} />
    {(this.state.isMouseInsideID === album.id) ? <button>Your Button</button> : null}
</div>
```

Its all fine except button is shown below the image.
But I want to show the button over the image or in the middle of the `div`

How can I make this work ?

Comment: using CSS, relatively or absolutely position the button where you want it

Comment: As @JaromandaX mentioned, Setting a relative/absolute with correct z-index, should do the job

Answer (score 2):

make button `position relative` and use `z-index:` maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I tried this `.mynew-btn{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 10px;
}` and its working but it is not on the center..

Comment: `.mynew-btn{position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-left:-50px;margin-top:-50px; z-index:10;}` try this one. https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/33yt3b21/

Answer (score 1):

Use **z-index** properties

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).. **Note: z-index only works on
>   positioned elements
>   (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).**

```
img {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can style button to achieve this ??

Comment: If you add .button { position: absolute; z-index: 10 ; } ? It doesn't work?

Comment: It appears after the image.. z index works but button appears after image `.mynew-btn{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 10px;
}`

Comment: @gamer can you write the img css??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the button in a div, while there is a background image to the div. I would suggest, to assign a background image for the div, rather than inserting an image into the div. Check out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/49s505sa/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <button type="button">Your Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150') /*assign image, for demo purposes */
}

button {
 height: 20px;
 position: relative;
 margin: -20px -50px;
 width: 100px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
}
```

So, inside the render method

```
var style = {
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + album.photos.data[0].source+ ')'
}
<div className={"panel-body"} style={style}>
    {(this.state.isMouseInsideID === album.id) ? <button>Your Button</button> : null}
</div>
```

In this way, we will dynamically assign images to particular divs. And wont have to worry too much about styling.

Hope that helps!

Comment: why r u using `backgroud` in css ??

Comment: That just to show you as an example. You can remove it from the CSS. I took it from fiddle, to explain.